# Wordpress, вывести сообщение при активации плагина

Tags: php, wordpress

Как правильно выводить сообщение пользователю, что плаги был успешно активировал или не возможно активировать плагин по конкретной ошибке

мой код

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: tested
 * Description: tested
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: tested tested
 * Requires at least: 5.2
 * Requires PHP: 7.0
 * @package tested
 */

// Define constants.
define('LOVAT_API_PLUGIN_VERSION', '1.0.0');
define('LOVAT_API_PLUGIN_DIR', untrailingslashit(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)));
define('LOVAT_API_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));

// Include the main class.
require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/class-lovat.php';

//// Load core packages and the autoloader.
include_once(LOVAT_API_PLUGIN_DIR . '/autoload.php');

//activate plugin, create
function activate_lovat_api()
{
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/class-lovat-activator.php';
    new Lovat_Activator();
}

//deactivate plugin
function deactivate_lovat_api()
{
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/class-lovat-deactivator.php';
    Lovat_Deactivator::deactivate();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_lovat_api' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_lovat_api' );

// Main instance of plugin.
function Lovat()
{
    return Lovat::instance();
}

// Global for backwards compatibility.
$GLOBALS['lovat_api'] = Lovat();
```

```
<?php

class Lovat_Activator
{

    private function __construct()
    {
        do_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'activate' ) ) ;
    }

    public static function activate()
    {
        if (is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) {
            global $wpdb;

            $table = $wpdb->prefix . "lovat_api_keys";
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

            if ($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '" . $table . "'") != $table) {
                $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
                      id int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      token VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                      user_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
                      created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
                    ) $charset_collate;";

                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
                dbDelta($sql);
            }
        } else {
            $html = '<div class="error">';
            $html .= '<p>';
            $html .= __('Для работы плагина, пожалуйста, установите или активируйте плагин WooCommerce');
            $html .= '</p>';
            $html .= '</div>';

            echo $html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://tommcfarlin.com/plugin-activation-message/ поможет?

Comment: я получаю ошибку "
The plugin has opened 164 symbols of the unassigned entry upon activation."

Comment: Не очень вас понял, я попробую дать вам ответ на ваш вопрос относительно поста выше

Comment: изменил код в моем вопросе, как сейчас у меня это выглядит

Answer (score 1):

Сообщения надо запускать вне хука активации плагина, а на постоянной основе

// Правим первую часть, инициализируем и запускаем нотификации

```
$activator = new Lovat_Activator();

function activate_lovat_api() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/class-lovat-activator.php';  
    // Вызываем ваш апи  
    $activator -> api();
}
```

// Правим вторую часть

```
// Lovat_Activator
class Lovat_Activator {
    private function __construct()  {
        do_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'admin_notices' ) ) ;
    }
    function api() {
        if (is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) {
          global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "lovat_api_keys";
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        if ($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '" . $table . "'") != $table) {
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
                  id int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  token VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                  user_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
                  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
                ) $charset_collate;";

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
            dbDelta($sql);
        }
      }
    }
    function admin_notices() {
        if (!is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) {
          $html = '<div class="error">';
          $html .= '<p>';
          $html .= __('Для работы плагина, пожалуйста, установите или активируйте плагин WooCommerce');
          $html .= '</p>';
          $html .= '</div>';
          echo $html;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Отредактировано**

Практика показывает, что лучше не использовать функцию **is_plugin_active**, так-как она доступна в определенное время и рекомендуется использовать при **admin_init** событии, для этих целей лучше подходят **function_exists** или **class_exists**

Comment: Когда я пытаюсь вывести сообщение, я получаю ошибку "Плагин создал 203 символы неожиданного выхода при активации. Если возникнет ошибка "headers already sent" с RSS-лентами или другие проблемы, то попробуйте отключить или удалить плагин."

Comment: Да, я постоянно получаю данную ошибку

Comment: как мне тогда быть? Мне нужно это проверять в плагине по время активации, я не пойму как правильно мне вставить код

Comment: Вам не нужно показывать их при активации, вам нужно их показывать всегда пока условие == true, то есть, пока плагин выключен, смотрите мой пример, я сделал изменения по вашему коду

Comment: Что-то вы написали какую-то огромную муть :)

Comment: Проблема в том, что пытаешься указать на ошибку, вложить какое-то понятие алгоритма, а получается, пока код не поправишь так, что бы он работал без ошибок, никто тебя не поймет, а печально, сократил